# _OBJC_CLASS_$_ScringoAgent", referenced from:

Tags: ios, xcode5.1, scringo, buzztouch

I am using Scringo in BuzzTouch iOS application - and creating an archive. It fails with the following error

```
(null): Ignoring file /Users/rbabu/Desktop/XCodeProjects/Development/selenagomez_iOS 1.4/Scringo/Scringo.framework/Scringo, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/rbabu/Desktop/XCodeProjects/Development/selenagomez_iOS 1.4/Scringo/Scringo.framework/Scringo (4 slices)

(null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ScringoAgent", referenced from:

(null): Objc-class-ref in justinbeiberquiz_appDelegate.o

(null): Objc-class-ref in BT_screen_menuButtons.o

(null): Objc-class-ref in BT_screen_quiz.o

(null): Objc-class-ref in BT_screen_customURL.o

(null): Objc-class-ref in Mac_image_gallery.o

(null): Objc-class-ref in WB_screen_menuImage.o

(null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The link works and runs for simulator fine. The failure is only when creating the archive

I put the ios `sdk Scringo-ios-sdk (v2.5.11)` which is the latest in Frameworks group.

Please provide some direction on answer what I should do to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

As the first line of your log says, the Scringo framework does not appear to have a 64-bit arm version. You should either ask them for one that does, or else turn off building for arm64. You can do this by changing your "Valid Architectures" build setting to not include arm64.

Comment: Thanks, brilliant! @Jesse Rusak - does it mean the app wont work on new 64 bit devices?

Answer (score 0):

Scringo 2.5.12 is now available and should have support for arm64.
Check it out on [Scringo's download page](http://www.scringo.com/docs/downloads/)